# How to replace a string with a specific value directly in SQL SELECT query (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, regexp-replace

I have a table with employee data inside:

```
+----+-------+----------+------------+
| ID | Name  | LastName | Salutation |
+----+-------+----------+------------+
|  1 | John  | Doe      | Mr         |
|  2 | Alice | Smith    | Ms         |
+----+-------+----------+------------+
```

I want to select some of that data but I want to replace `Mr` with `1` and `Ms` with `2` using the SQL query itself.

I have tried to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` what actually did work for one of the salutations:

```
SELECT ID, Name, LastName, REGEXP_REPLACE(Salutation, 'Mr', '1') FROM employees
```

It gave me a following result:

```
+----+-------+----------+------------+
| ID | Name  | LastName | Salutation |
+----+-------+----------+------------+
|  1 | John  | Doe      | 1          |
|  2 | Alice | Smith    | Ms         |
|  3 | John  | Smith    | 1          |
|  4 | Alice | Doe      | Ms         |
+----+-------+----------+------------+
```

How can I replace also `Ms` to `2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `decode`

```
select ID, Name, LastName.
    DECODE(Salutation,'Mr',1,2) as Salutation
from employee
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using `case` statement. Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7836d41ef8666d095b06ae77a9025405)

```
select
    ID,
    Name,
    LastName,
    (case when Salutation = 'Mr' then 1  else 2 end) as Salutation
from employee
order by
    ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ID, Name, LastName,
    REPLACE(TMP_TABLE.TMP_Salutation, 'Ms', '2')
FROM (
    SELECT
    REPLACE(Salutation, 'Mr', '1') TMP_Salutation
    FROM employees
) TMP_TABLE;
```

This code will first replace all occurances of 'Mr' with '1' in the subquery and return a table which we gave an alias of 'TMP_TABLE'. Then, all the occurances of 'Ms' in that 'TMP_TABLE' will be replaced with '2'

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.